# Coverage of rules files generated by bison

Tags: code-coverage, bison

I have a really huge bison rules file and was wondering if there is an easy way to get a coverage of those rules from the program behind.

I generate a parser with bison. Run the parser against different files and want to see which lines have been touched in the **.yy** file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official way to generate such a report, as far as I know. But it's possible to do, if you're willing to break into bison's internals a bit.

Note that you can only produce a coverage report for parser semantic actions. There's no other direct translation for "parser rules"; the rules are compiled into a state machine, and the correspondence from state to rule is many-to-many. But that will tell you how many times each rule was completed, which is probably what you want to know.

Also note that the parser does not distinguish between rule final semantic actions and mid-rule actions, since mid-rule actions are actually compiled into reduction actions for generated non-terminals.

The rest of this post is unofficial, and should not be relied on to work with all future versions of Bison. Nor will it work with other Bison skeletons (although it could presumably be adapted); I wrote based on the current release, version 3.8.2.

The easiest way to hook into the parser is to hijack the macro `YY_REDUCE_PRINT`, which is used by the trace facility to trace reduction actions. So it is executed every time a reduction takes place. That happens even if tracing is not compiled into the parser; in that case, the macro is defined as a no-op. `YY_REDUCE_PRINT` is not an official part of the interface, though, so its name and functionality might change without notice. Also, it's not officially available for customization, and the generated source makes no attempt to check if it was previously defined. So you have to wait until it has been defined in the parser template, and then redefine it. Of course, redefining it will make it unavailable for trace logs, so this is not compatible with debugging traces. It turns out that the `½initial-action` code block is injected after the definition of `YY_REDUCE_PRINT`, so that's where I put the redefinition. That's not guaranteed either.

I tested the following code, very lightly, with a couple of recent bison versions (3.7.1 and 3.8.2), using the `lalr1.cc` skeleton. It seems to work, but your mileage may vary.

The code is very simple. First, the redefinition of `YY_REDUCE_PRINT`, which goes into your `.yy` file. You might want to make it conditional on some configuration macro, in order to retain the possibility of generating debug traces. All that the redefined `YY_REDUCE_PRINT` macro does is add one to a coverage histogram. (Here, `drv` is an instance of the parser driver, as per the Calc++ example):

```cpp
%initial-action {
#undef YY_REDUCE_PRINT
#define YY_REDUCE_PRINT(Rule) drv.register_rule(Rule)
}
```

The histogram itself needs to be implemented; it can go into `driver.hh` and `driver.cc`:

Header:

```cpp
  // Register execution of a semantic action.
  void register_rule(int rule);
  // Count of executions of each rule.
  std::vector<unsigned> rule_count;
```

Implementation:

```cpp
void
driver::register_rule(int ruleno) {
  if (ruleno > 0) {
    if (ruleno > rule_count.size()) rule_count.resize(ruleno);
    ++rule_count[ruleno - 1];
  } 
}
```

The rule numbers correspond to the numbers in the generated report files. Rule 0 (the accepting rule) will not be counted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using bison 3.6 :
The syntax tree is built and printed for LaTex in texput.tex

syntaxtree-2.y:

```
%{
/*
 Einfacher Baum aus Strings, typedef genügt
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "tree.hpp"
typedef tree<string> syntaxTree;
syntaxTree * syntaxTree_epsilon_node () {
    return new syntaxTree("$\\epsilon$");
}
syntaxTree * root;

int yylex();
int yyerror(string s);
#define YYDEBUG 1
%}
%union {syntaxTree * tree;}
%token t_plus t_minus t_mal t_div t_kla_auf t_kla_zu t_fehler t_zahl
%initial-action {
#undef  YY_REDUCE_PRINT
#define YY_REDUCE_PRINT(Rule) { if (yytname[yyr1[Rule]][0] != '$') { \
        int n = 0; \
        root = yyval.tree = new syntaxTree(yytname[yyr1[Rule]]); \
        for (int i = 1 - yyr2[Rule]; i <= 0; i++) \
            if (yytname[YY_ACCESSING_SYMBOL (yyssp[i])][0] != '$') \
                n++, yyval.tree->append(yyvsp[i].tree); \
        if (!n) yyval.tree->append(syntaxTree_epsilon_node()); \
    } \
}
} // %initial-action
%%
expr: term | expr t_plus {} term | expr t_minus term {};
term: factor | term t_mal {} factor| term t_div factor;
factor: t_zahl | t_kla_auf expr t_kla_zu | t_minus factor;
%%
#include "lex.yy.c"

int yyerror(string s) {
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int rc =  yyparse();
    if (!rc)
        root->tikz("texput.tex");
    else
        cerr <<  "Parse-Ergebnis " << rc << endl;
    return rc;
}
```

scanner-2.l:

```
%{
#define PROCESS(id) {\
    yylval.tree =  new syntaxTree(yytext); \
    return id;\
}
%}
%%
"+"         PROCESS(t_plus);
"-"         PROCESS(t_minus);
"*"         PROCESS(t_mal);
"/"         PROCESS(t_div);
"("         PROCESS(t_kla_auf);
")"         PROCESS(t_kla_zu);
[0-9]+      PROCESS(t_zahl);
[ \t\n]     /* do nothing */;
.           PROCESS(t_fehler);
%%
int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
```

tree.hpp:

```
/*
 
Template-Klasse tree
 
*/

#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
template <class T> class tree {
public:
    tree();
    ~tree();
    tree(T);
    tree(T, tree<T> *);
    tree(T, tree<T> *, tree<T> *);
    tree(T, tree<T> *, tree<T> *, tree<T> *);
    tree(T, vector<tree<T> *>);
    void set(const T & p);
    T get();
    void ascii(ostream & o = cout, int level = 0);
    void tikz(ostream & o = cout, int level = 0, int path = 0);
    void tikz(string filename, int path = 0);
    void postorder(ostream & o = cout, int level = 0);
    void append(tree *);
    vector<tree<T> *> & childs();
    tree<T> * childs(int);
    int size();
    tree * parent;
    tree<T> * operator [] (int);
protected:
    vector<tree *> child;
    T v;
    void tikz_path(ostream & o = cout, int level = 0);
};


template <class T> tree<T> * tree<T>::operator [] (int index) {
    return (index < 0 || index >= child.size()) ? nullptr : child[index];
}

template <class T> int tree<T>::size() {
    return child.size();
}

template <class T> tree<T>::tree(T _v) :v(_v) {}

template <class T> tree<T>::tree(T _v ,tree<T> * p) : v(_v) {
    append(p);
}

template <class T> tree<T>::tree(T _v ,tree<T> * p1, tree<T> * p2) : v(_v) {
    append(p1), append(p2);
}

template <class T> tree<T>::tree(T _v ,tree<T> * p1, tree<T> * p2, tree<T> * p3) : v(_v) {
    append(p1), append(p2), append(p3);
}

template <class T> tree<T>::tree(T _v, vector<tree<T> *> childs) : v(_v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < childs.size(); i++)
        append(childs[i]);
}


template <class T>  tree<T>::tree() {
}

template <class T>  tree<T>::~tree() {
    //for (auto i: child) delete i; // C++ 11 !!!!
        
    for (int i = 0; i < child.size(); i++)
        delete child[i];
}

template <class T> void tree<T>::set(const T & _v) {
    v = _v;
}

template <class T> T tree<T>::get() {
    return v;
}


template <class T> void tree<T>::append(tree * t) {
    if (t != nullptr) {
        child.push_back(t);
        t->parent = this;
    }
}

template <class T> vector<tree<T> *> & tree<T>::childs() {
    return child;
}

template <class T> tree<T> * tree<T>::childs(int n) {
    return (n < 0 || n >= child.size()) ? nullptr : child[n];
}

template <class T> void tree<T>::ascii(ostream & o, int level) {
    for (unsigned i=0; i < level; i++)
        o << "\t";
    o << v << " " << child.size() << endl;
    for (unsigned i=0; i < child.size(); i++) {
        child[i]->ascii(o, level + 1);
    }
}

template <class T> void tree<T>::postorder(ostream & o, int level) {
    for (unsigned i=0; i < child.size(); i++) {
        child[i]->postorder(o, level + 1);
    }
    o << v << " ";
    if (!level)
        o << endl;
}

template <class T> void tree<T>::tikz(string filename, int path) {
    fstream f;
    f.open (filename, fstream::out);
    tikz(f, 0, path);
    f.close();
}

template <class T> void tree<T>::tikz(ostream & o, int n, int path) {
    // Baum-Traversierung First-Order
    int i;
    if (!n) {
        o << "\\documentclass{standalone}\n";
        o << "\\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree}\n";
        o << "\\begin{document}\n";
        // "Normale" Baumansicht
        o << "\\begin{tikzpicture}\n[level distance=1.25cm,sibling distance=.25cm,every tree node/.style={anchor=north,align=center,draw,top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,minimum width=1.5em,minimum height=1.5em},every leaf node/.style={anchor=north,align=center,draw,rounded corners,top color=white, bottom color=red!20,minimum width=1.5em,minimum height=1.5em},blank/.style={draw=none,color=white!0, top color=white!0, bottom color=white!0},"
        // Horizontal wachsend, ggf. optisch geeigneter für Hohe Bäume und Hochformatansicht
        //o << [grow'=right,level distance=4cm,sibling distance=.25cm,every tree node/.style={anchor= west,align=center,draw,top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,minimum width=1.5em,,minimum height=1.5em},every leaf node/.style={anchor=north,align=center,draw,rounded corners,top color=white, bottom color=red!20,minimum width=1.5em,minimum height=1.5em},blank/.style={draw=none,color=white!0, top color=white!0, bottom color=white!0},]
        "]";
        o << "\n\\Tree\n";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    o << "\t";
    if (child.size()) {
        o << "[." << "\\node(" << this << "){" << v << "};" << endl;
        for (unsigned i=0; i < child.size(); i++)
            child[i]->tikz(o, n + 1);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        o << "\t";
        o << "]\n";
    }
    else
        o << "" << "\\node(" << this << "){" << v << "};" << endl;
    if (!n) {
        if (path)
            tikz_path(o, 0);
        o << "\\end{tikzpicture}\n";
        o << "\\end{document}\n";
    }
    
}

template <class T> void tree<T>::tikz_path(ostream & o, int level) {
    if (!level)
        o << "\\draw [red, >->] plot [smooth, tension=.75] coordinates {\n";
    if (child.size() == 0) {
        o << "([xshift=-4mm]" << this << ")\n";
        o << "([yshift=-4mm]" << this << ")\n";
        o << "([xshift=+4mm]" << this << ")\n";
    }
/*  else if (child.size() == 1) {
        o << "([xshift=-4mm]" << this << ")\n";
        child[0]->tikz_path(o, level + 1);
        o << "([xshift=+4mm]" << this << ")\n";
    }*/
    else if (child.size() == 2) {
        o << "([xshift=-4mm]" << this << ")\n";
        child[0]->tikz_path(o, level + 1);
        o << "([yshift=-4mm]" << this << ")\n";
        child[1]->tikz_path(o, level + 1);
        o << "([xshift=+4mm]" << this << ")\n";
    }
    else  {
        o << "([xshift=-4mm]" << this << ")\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < child.size(); i++)
            child[i]->tikz_path(o, level + 1);
        o << "([xshift=+4mm]" << this << ")\n";
    }
    if (!level)
        o << "};\n";
}
```

make:

```
syntaxtree-2: syntaxtree-2.y scanner-2.l
    lex scanner-2.l
    bison syntaxtree-2.y -o y.tab.cpp
    ${CPP} y.tab.cpp -I${INCL} -o syntaxtree-2
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**